# Wordpress post view format for filter grid

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I am a complete newb to wordpress.  I am trying to help a friend out.  She asked me to help her move her wordpress instance to another hosting provider.

I have done that for the most part.  My issue is the original provider implemented a not-so-obvious way of an isotope filter on some UI elements.

Specifically the object is a company.  Each company has a logo, the name of the company, a short description and a contact name / email.

These companies service states / areas and the idea behind the page is to select the state and only the companies for that state are visible.

From the brief searching I have done - there seems to be an overwhelming amount of plugins to support this.

I have tried creating a simple post with a featured image and adding in the text in the excerpt.

My problem is the links.  I don't want the links to go back to the post - rather I want the links to go to a custom URL.

Is there a plugin that will allow me to define a custom post type (to include categories) and then filter on it similar to Isotope type of filtering?

Answer (score 0):

There are many free plugins but if you are using the Elementor page builder. I am not advertising my product but as I saw your requirement matches a plugin that I am selling in the market.
The frontend filtering feature is not yet available to the released version but will be released soon. It basically allows you to build a custom grid as you like.
Is it something similar?
https://demo.geekygreenowl.com/elementor-387/

You have to create a custom post, there should be a custom field(custom URL) as well.

Or, You may create a WordPress query. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/
also, coding will be required for filtering